# Pandas groupby and aggregate duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like the one below.

```
d = {'location': ['canada', 'canada', 'italy', 'italy'], 'item': ['coke', 'coke', 'pepsi', 'coke'], 'weight': [1, 1, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
  location item  weight
0  canada  coke    1
1  canada  coke    1
2   italy  pepsi   2
3   italy  coke    1
```

In the dataframe each row for location should have a unique item name and corresponding weight for the item. However due to data quality issues sometimes items are reported multiple times. In this case I would like to sum the weights across the multiple items and then show aggregated weight for a single item.

The result would look like this

```
df
  location item  weight
0  canada  coke    2
1   italy  pepsi   2
2   italy  coke    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use transform and then drop duplicates.

```
d = {'location': ['canada', 'canada', 'italy', 'italy'], 'item': ['coke', 'coke', 'pepsi', 'coke'], 'weight': [1, 1, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['weight'] = df.groupby(['location', 'item']).transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates()

df.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[1]: 
  location   item  weight
0   canada   coke       2
1    italy  pepsi       2
2    italy   coke       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Or simply `sum` on weight after `groupby`:

```
print (df.groupby(["location","item"])["weight"].sum().reset_index())
#
  location   item  weight
0   canada   coke       2
1    italy   coke       1
2    italy  pepsi       2
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.groupby` can do it,

```py
df = df.groupby(['location', 'item']).sum()
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

the result like this:

```
   location   item  weight
0   canada   coke       2
1    italy   coke       1
2    italy  pepsi       2
```

the index of `df` is `['location', 'item']` when use `groupby(['location', 'item'])`, then use `reset—index` can set the index of df to value.

Refer: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby